# Point Size with X11 Fonts

Tags: linux, fonts, xorg, truetype, terminator

I'm trying to set up my fonts on a bare bones X windows system, but my settings aren't giving me the results I expect.

I'm using Terminator as my terminal.  I've set my Terminator font to "Monospace 9".  My ~/.Xresources specifies a system DPI of 120 via "Xft.dpi: 120".  My screen has a resolution of 1600x900.

The 9pt monospaced font evaluates to 1/8th in., since 1pt = 1/72in.  As I understand it, X windows then uses the dpi setting of 120 to convert this into pixels.  120 * (1/8) = 15px, so a row of text should take up 15px of vertical height.  That would mean that my terminal should show 900/15 = 60 rows of text.  However, even at full screen, my terminal shows just under 50 rows of text, meaning the font is being rendered at 900/50 = 18px.

Where did my reasoning go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think 9pt font refers to the width of the character, not height. So you should count the number of columns, not row